# What is equivalent for $(command) of UNIX-like terminal in Windows terminal?

Tags: command-line, terminal

For example, in UNIX-like terminal,

```
$ pkg-config --libs libssl
-lssl -lcrypto
```

Then, I can pass the output directly to `gcc` with:

```
$ gcc $(pkg-config) main.c
```

which is identical to:

```
$ gcc -lssl -crypto main.c
```

I wonder if there is an equivalent for this in Windows terminal (`cmd.exe`)

Comment: This should help: https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take Windows Terminal as Windows [PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/mt173057.aspx), then it is *still* `$(cmd)`.

You can try it yourself by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcut to pop up the Run menu and type `powershell` to bring up the newer, blue screen, de facto & somewhat de jure (`:P`) Windows terminal.

PS:

For, `cmd.exe` you can store the result in `.txt` files and read its contents using `for /f` built-in command.

PPS:

For Microsoft Visual Basic (`.vbs`) you can store the result in an object by using the `Exec` method as follows:

```
Set myObject = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("%ComSpec% /c cmd")
```

Here `%comspec%` (in Windows case doesn't matter) stands for `cmd.exe` being an environment variable containing the location of the `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` Command Prompt executable.

Append `StdOut.ReadAll` to the created object to access its contents.